# My application which works with task scheduler can't create directory in my c# code

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, task, exe, manual-testing

My application has a code part like that:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(datePath))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(datePath);
}
```

If I double click and run exe, it works and creates folders.

But when I take my application to task scheduler and set to run every day, the code doesn't work. No error, nothing.

Even if I right click on task and run it manually, it doesn't work.

I use my other applications with task scheduler and they work fine. I don't understand why this one doesn't create directories....

Comment: The user account will need to be permission to create the directory. i.e. the user account that's running the task scheduler.

Comment: Sounds like a file permissions problem. Have to set the task to run with your credentials?

Comment: Your logon user and user running the scheduler are different.

Comment: What is the value of `datePath`?

Comment: Finish part of creating task I used the admin id/pw

Comment: I dont think it is a permission problem, because if I run exe by clicking on it at the server, it works. Also I used server admin id and pw.

Comment: string datePath = "E:\\ENGINEERING\\WELDING_DATA\\L202\\2014\\DECEMBER"

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question. This code either creates the directory or throws an exception. If neither happens, something else is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tying the [comment on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547053/my-application-which-works-with-task-scheduler-cant-create-directory-in-my-c-sh#comment43521276_27547053) and your [comment on my now-removed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547053/my-application-which-works-with-task-scheduler-cant-create-directory-in-my-c-sh#comment43522531_27547105) together:

> You see path is `E:\Engineering\2014\December`. E: is a mapped drive to `\\server\share`.
>
> I used server admin user and password for the Scheduled Task

That user has no mapped drives on your machine. Use the full UNC path:

```
string datePath = @"\\server\share\Engineering\..."
```